# Safari progress bar incomplete on HLS stream

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, http-live-streaming

I'm transcoding videos to HLS and am able to validate the stream via:

```
$mediastreamvalidator <url-to-master-playlist.m3u8>
```

Mediastreamvalidator gives no errors and all segments *seem* ok.

However on many videos the progress bar contains a small white/unloaded segment which never changes despite the video segments fully loading.  Does this have to do with my encoding properties?

Here is the mediastreamvalidator output for one of the errant segments:

```
Processed 3 out of 3 segments
Average segment duration: 3.686918
Total segment bitrates (all discontinuities): average: 2293.51 kb/s, max: 2562.78 kb/s
Playlist max bitrate: 2374.000000 kb/s
Audio Group ID: AUDIO


Discontinuity: sequence: 0, parsed segment count: 3 of 3, duration: 11.061 sec, average: 2293.51 kb/s, max: 2562.78 kb/s
Track ID: 1
Audio Codec: AAC-LC
Audio sample rate: 44100 Hz
Audio channel layout: Stereo (L R)
Track ID: 2
Video Codec: avc1
Video profile: Main
Video level: 3.1
Video resolution: 480x360
Video average IDR interval: 3.409137, Standard deviation: 0.000005
Video frame rate: 26.400
```

[image: progress bar never loads]

[image]